# delete duplicates using pig where there is no primary key

Tags: hadoop, duplicates, apache-pig

Im a newbie to hadoop and I have a use case where there are 3 columns name,value,time stamp.The data is , comma separated and is in csv format I need to check for the duplicates and delete them using pig.How can I achieve that.

Comment: You should refer to PIG Latin reference here: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html. You will get the answer

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.Actually i have hive external tables created on this data.so I would like to know how we can actually delete the duplicates and does it affect the current hive tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pig `DISTINCT` function to remove duplicate. 
Please refer this [link](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#DISTINCT)  to know about `DISTINCT` function.

As you are saying that your data reside in HIVE table and you want to access those data through pig, You can use `HCatLoader()` to access HIVE table through pig. `HCatalog` can be used for both external and internal `HIVE` table. But before using this function, please verify that your cluster has configured `HCatalog`. If you are using Hadoop 2.X then it should be there.

Using HCatalog your pig `LOAD` command will be like this.

```
A = LOAD 'table_name' using HCatLoader();
```

If you don't want to use `HCatalog` and if your `HIVE` tables are `external` table and you know the HDFS location of the data then you can use `CSVLoader()` to access the data. Using `CSVLoader()` your pig `LOAD` command will be like this.

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar
define CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
--Load data using CSVLoader.
A = LOAD '/user/hdfs/dirtodata/MyData.csv' using CSVLoader AS (
              name:chararray, value:chararray, timestamp:chararray,
);
```

Hive external tables are designed in such a way that user can access
the data from outside hive such as Pig and MapReduce programming. But if your `HIVE` table is internal table and you want to analyze the data using Pig, then you can use `HCatLoader()` to access hive table data through pig.

In both scenario there wont be any effect in original data during the analytic. Here you are accessing the data, you are not modifying the original data.

Please refer below useful link to understand more about HCat.

http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-use-hcatalog-basic-pig-hive-commands/

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+UsingHCat

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have tried distinct and it worked and was pretty simple..My apologies as i assumed the issue to be a much bigger one and posted the qsn.